# $A$ closed, strictly convex set, $\mu$ non-degenerate probability measure on $\partial A$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_{\partial A}x\mu(dx) \in A^°$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $A\subset\Bbb R^d$ a closed, strictly convex set. Denote by $\partial A$ its topological boundary and by $A^°$ its interior.

Is it true that if $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\partial A$ that is not a Dirac measure, then

$$ \int_{\partial A}x\mu(dx) \in A^°,$$

i.e. its mean is contained in the interior?

If $\mu$ is discrete, it has to be a convex combination of Dirac measures, and then the claim follows immediately from the strict convexity of $A$. However, I'm not sure if that even helps for the general case, since this property can theoretically get lost in the limit if we use approximation arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.
Let $f$ be a nonzero linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x) \le b$ for all $x \in A$.  Then
$$ f\left(\int_{\partial A} x\; \mu(dx)\right) = \int_{\partial A} f(x)\; \mu(dx) \le b$$
Now by strict convexity there can be at most one $x_0 \in A$ such that $f(x_0) = b$,  so
if $\mu$ is not the Dirac measure at $x_0$ we must have $f\left(\int_{\partial A} x \mu(dx)\right) < b$.

But that implies that $\int_{\partial A} x \mu(dx)$ is in the interior of $A$, as otherwise we could take a supporting hyperplane to $A$ there.

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like you assume that $A$ is also bounded, right?

Comment: Where did I assume that?

Comment: How do you get a finite $b$ if $A$ is unbounded?

Comment: Unbounded convex sets also have [supporting hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) at their boundary points.